# Get command line parameters as one large string

Tags: c, winapi

I know that I can get the whole command line with

```
LPWSTR commandLine = GetCommandLineW();
```

and get all parts from it

```
int argv = 0;
LPWSTR* szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(commandLine, &argv);
```

but when launching

```
$ myapp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

this always contains the name of the executable itself (`myapp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3`).

How can I get just all parameters as one large string (`arg1 arg2 arg3`).

Comment: you can concatenate the parameters in your program into one string using `strcat`

Comment: If you have `char *t = "myapp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3";` use `t+10` for `"arg1 arg2 arg3"`, eg: `printf("arguments: %s\n", t+10);`

Comment: @pmg - The actual size to increase, (+10) is dependent on the name of the executable, and in some environments on the path and cwd.

Comment: @pmg: The `+10` part is not a good idea. They could call it with `"myapp"` or `"c:\program files\whatever\myapp.exe"`.

Comment: Would it be safe to use the length of `szArgList[0]` as offset?

Comment: No, it is not safe, `commandLine` can be `"C:\path\my.exe" "foo bar"` while `argv[0]` is just `C:\path\my.exe` (without quotes).

Comment: Passing the name of the application used to create the process as the first command line argument is a C *convention*. It is a command line argument like all the others, and it need not be the application name. See [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "How can I get just all parameters as one large string", what do you actually mean?

If you want the exact parameters used to create the process you just call `GetCommandLine` and skip the first argument. If the string starts with a `"` you skip until you find the closing `"`, otherwise you skip until you find a space; `while(*cmd > ' ') ++cmd;` or something along those lines.

If you want the parameters after they have been processed you need to concatenate all the `argv` strings from `1` to `argc -1`. What processed means depends on your C run-time library if you get them from `main()`. `CommandLineToArgvW`s processing of quotes and backslashes is documented on MSDN. Because the parameters have been processed, you cannot use this concatenated string to launch other processes since required quotes may have been removed.

Comment: Are you sure that `argv[0]` and the beginning of `commandLine` only can differ by surrounding quotes? Is there a reverse of `CommandLineToArgvW` available that does all the required escaping/quoting?

Comment: Did I say they only differ by quotes? `main()` is not a Windows thing, the C run-time builds `argv` and therefore it is up to the implementation. There is no function in the WinAPI but basically `GetCommandLine` is the reverse of `CommandLineToArgvW`.

Answer (score -4):

You can concatenate the parameters in your program. A small snippet is below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char concat[100] = ""; // decide size appropriately
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i< argc; i++)
        {
            strcat(concat, argv[i]);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Edit - The solution suggested is a quick and easy output which will not work for all cases. e.g. It does not support for unicode characters. If required, can be made better by allocating the memory for the concataneted string dynamically. Also, this solution does not add spaces in between the arguments. If required, that also can be added.

Comment: It's arguably better to make 2 passes: the first to size the target string (and not forgetting to add space separaters).

Comment: this doesn't work if `argv[i]` contains spaces or complex nested quotes

Comment: The answer is not a good one - it takes 100 as arbitrary size and fails miserably of the command line is longer. It does not care about unicode.

Comment: Why the redundant `argc >= 2` check? The `for` loop does that already.